Decomposing the matrix multiplication tensor with unitary 2-designs
The question concerns equation (5) from the paper Designing Strassen’s Algorithm.
The tensor associated with matrix multiplication (say in $(\mathbb{C}^{n\times n})^{\otimes3}$) is given in the paper as
$$
\mathsf{MM}_{def}^{abc}=\delta_e^a\delta_f^b\delta_d^c
$$
a fancy way talking about matrix multiplication (as in this question).  The paper calls this a "twisted" version of $I^{\otimes 3}$, whose coefficients could be written as
$$
\delta_d^a\delta_e^b\delta_f^c.
$$
Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ such that
$$
\sum_{v\in S}v=0,\quad \frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{v\in S}|v\rangle\langle v|=\frac{1}{n}I,
$$
which the paper calls a unitary 2-design.
Suppose $S=\{w_1,\ldots, w_s\}$.  Then equation (6) of the paper says
$$
I^{\otimes 3}=\frac{n^3}{s^3}\sum_{i,j,k}|w_i\rangle\langle w_i|\otimes|w_j\rangle\langle w_j|\otimes|w_k\rangle\langle w_k|
$$
which is obvious by cubing the second property of 2-designs above, but equation (5) of the paper says
$$
\mathsf{MM}=\frac{n^3}{s^3}\sum_{i,j,k}|w_i\rangle\langle w_j|\otimes|w_j\rangle\langle w_k|\otimes|w_k\rangle\langle w_i|
$$
which is not obvious to me at all, but supposedly follows from the second property of the 2-design and the definition of $\mathsf{MM}$.
Can someone explain why (5) is true???  Everything else in the paper makes sense to me except this one line...

It might be worthwhile to ask in https://mathoverflow.net/ or https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get good reception here. There is also https://cs.stackexchange.com but that is meant for an audience similar to https://math.stackexchange.com

As you mentioned, the matrix multiplication is a "twisted" $I^{\otimes 3}$, which means that if we consider $MM$ and $I^{\otimes 3}$ as sixth order tensors in $\mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^* \otimes \mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^* \otimes \mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^*$, then
$$\mathsf{MM} = \sum_{i,j,k = 1}^n \left|i\rangle\langle j\right| \otimes \left|j\rangle\langle k\right| \otimes \left|k\rangle\langle i\right|$$
is obtained from
$$I^{\otimes 3} = \sum_{i,j,k = 1}^n \left|i\rangle\langle i\right| \otimes \left|j\rangle\langle j\right| \otimes \left|k\rangle\langle k\right|$$
By applying a linear map
$$\mathrm{twist} \colon \mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^* \otimes \mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^* \otimes \mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^* \to \mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^* \otimes \mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^* \otimes \mathbb{C}^n \otimes (\mathbb{C}^n)^*$$
which permutes the factors of a sixth-order tensor accordingly. More specifically, for decomposable tensors we have
$$\mathrm{twist}\colon \left|u\rangle\langle v\right| \otimes \left|w\rangle\langle x\right| \otimes \left|y\rangle\langle z\right| \mapsto \left|u\rangle\langle x\right| \otimes \left|w\rangle\langle z\right| \otimes \left|y\rangle\langle v\right|.$$
Now, you say that you understand that
$$I^{\otimes 3} = \frac{n^3}{s^3} \sum_{i,j,k} \left|w_i \rangle\langle w_i\right| \otimes \left|w_j \rangle\langle w_j\right| \otimes \left|w_k \rangle\langle w_k\right|.$$
By twisting we obtain
$$\mathsf{MM} = \mathrm{twist}(I^{\otimes 3}) = \frac{n^3}{s^3} \sum_{i,j,k} \mathrm{twist}(\left|w_i \rangle\langle w_i\right| \otimes \left|w_j \rangle\langle w_j\right| \otimes \left|w_k \rangle\langle w_k\right|)=$$
$$=\frac{n^3}{s^3} \sum_{i,j,k} \left|w_i \rangle\langle w_j\right| \otimes \left|w_j \rangle\langle w_k\right| \otimes \left|w_k \rangle\langle w_i\right|.$$
